# How to move tab to a new window in a browser extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

The following is not working all the time, just sometimes:

```js
let win = await browser.windows.create()
await browser.tabs.move(tab.id, {index: 0, windowId: win.id})
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem with how I'm using the api.

Answer (score 0):

I checked some github repo and found they do this:

```js
browser.tabs.create({active: true, url: tab.url})
```

That actually works.